# Stop highlighting and cursor appearing when program changes value of QDoubleSpinBox

Tags: qt, qspinbox

Is it possible to make it so that if I set a value for a spin box within the program it does not highlight the changed field, or add a cursor. I have included the code for some of the slots below, which controls a minimum and maximum field and changes the other if min>max etc. The second slot exhibits the desired behavior but crashes if you click a spin control after typing the value(without return). All my spin boxes have keyboardtracking off.

```
void show_graph::on_vmin_dspinBox_valueChanged(double arg1)
{
active = false; /*flag to stop cyclic interactions*/
if (arg1>=ui->vmax_dSpinBox->value())
    {
    ui->vmax_dSpinBox->setValue(arg1);
    ui->vmax_dSpinBox->stepUp();
    }
active = true;
}
```

The second method is ugly and tries to manipulate focus.

```
void show_graph::on_fmin_dspinBox_valueChanged(double arg1)
{
active = false;
QWidget *active_item;
if (QApplication::focusWidget()!=0)
        active_item = QApplication::focusWidget(); /*save focus*/
if (arg1>=ui->fmax_dspinBox->value())
    {
    ui->fmax_dspinBox->setValue(arg1);
    ui->fmax_dspinBox->stepUp();
    }
ui->fmax_dspinBox->cursor(); /*move focus to changed widget*/
ui->fmax_dspinBox->setFocus();
ui->fmax_dspinBox->unsetCursor(); /*then remove to lose highlight and cursor*/
ui->fmax_dspinBox->clearFocus();
active_item->setFocus(); /*know I'm missing check of if active item set but this doesn't appear to be the issue*/
active_item->cursor(); /*reset focus/cursor to where user wanted*/
active = true;
}
```

The above code also crashed when used in a editingFinished slot. Tried to get a screen-shot of the problem but pressing print screen removes the unwanted highlighting/cursor.
I'm new to QT and therefore if this is a silly way of doing this please say so, or if the answer lies in the documentation please point me in the right direction. I'm developing and testing on Linux if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, for all user editable controls, programmatically changing the value should not affect focus at all. The spin box has what appears to be a bug in this area.

The workaround is not to use the `stepBy` API - use `setValue` instead.

Since calling `stepUp` is equivalent to incrementing the value by a single step, the fix is to change your code as follows:

```
ui->vmax_dSpinBox->setValue(arg1 + ui->vmax_dSpinBox->singleStep());
```